# Linear programming optimization problem formulation

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

I need help in formulating an optimization problem. I have a system of equations as follows:
    $c_1x_1+c_2x_2+c_3x_3=1$
    $b_1x_1+b_2x_2+b_3x_3=1$
    $a_1x_1+a_2x_2+a_3x_3=1$
In my case the system is not necessarily in three variables (the number of variables can increase).

The chosen $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$ should also satisfy the following system of equations:
    $c_1'x_1+c_2'x_2+c_3'x_3<1$
    $b_1'x_1+b_2'x_2+b_3'x_3<1$
    $a_1'x_1+a_2'x_2+a_3'x_3<1$
where
$0<c_1'<c_1$, $0<c_2'<c_2$, $0<c_3'<c_3$
$0<b_1'<b_1$, $0<b_2'<b_2$, $0<b_3'<b_3$
$0<a_1'<a_1$, $0<a_2'<a_2$, $0<a_3'<a_3$

I have no idea where should I look for a solution. Any pointers in the right direction would also be appreciated.

**UPDATE**: I understand that the constraints $0<c_1'<c_1$, $0<c_2'<c_2$, $0<c_3'<c_3$ would form a rectangular area and the value of $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$ should be chosen so that over this rectangular area the inequalities should be met. But I don't know how to formulate the constraints into an equation.

Comment: And what are you trying to actually optimize? It seems you've just listed some constraints. And what kind of answer are you looking for? A general result, or just a method that you can use for specific instances (e.g., the simplex algorithm)?

Comment: I understand that I can formulate the first set of equations as minimizing a least squares optimization (l2 norm) problem. But I don't know how to formulate the constraints into an equation. I would prefer a general result but first I need help in formulating the constraints....

Comment: So you just want to find *any* solution to those linear equations/inequalities?

Comment: I want a solution for the first set of equations subject to the constraints given in inequalities.

Comment: Wait, are $a_1',b_1',c_1'$, etc. *given*, or are you trying to *find* them? If the latter, then this is a nonconvex problem, and neither the linear-programming nor the convex-optimization tags are remotely appropriate.

Comment: Actually, nevermind. It looks like the inequalities are *trivially satisfied*. Assuming all of the original coefficients are positive, it will always be possible to chose the accented ones to ensure that the constraints are met, even in the overdetermined case.

Comment: You don't have to "formulate a constraint" on positive coefficients that are already given to you, $a_i'$, etc..  If you have to choose the accented coefficients, then that's a different problem (though as Michael Grant points out, it's always possible to choose them between zero and the unaccented coefficients).

Comment: No I don't have to choose values for accented coefficients. It's just that my system is a time varying system in which accented coefficients increase in value from 0 to 1. I want to ensure that when the value of accented coefficients are equal to non-accented coefficients, only then their linear combination is equal to 1. And the value for $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ should be such that their linear combination is less than 1 when either of $c_1'$, $c_2'$ and $c_3'$ lie in the range $[0,c_1)$, $[0,c_2)$ and $[0,c_3)$ respectively. And value for $c_1$, $c_2$ and $c_3$ are known to me.

Comment: Then you are effectively requiring $x$ to be nonnegative. When $x_i<0$, the value of the linear combination will exceed 1 if you reduce $a_i$, $b_i$, or $c_i$.

Comment: I agree with you that if $x_i$'s are restricted to be positive than  the inequalities would automatically be satisfied. But the problem with this approach is that it limits my solution space. Lets say I have the following scenario $c_1>c_2>c_3$. In such a case if I have positive $x_1$ and $x_2$, and a negative $x_3$, the inequalities would still be satisfied. I want to include such values for $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ to be considered as possible solutions.